# if a span contain a specific text add a display:none;

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.views-field-nothing').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.comments-toggle').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.comments-toggle:contains('Anonimo')').css("display", "none");    
    });   
});
```

at first it must show the comment field clicking on View-field-nothing (slideToggle) then if it find "Anonimo" it should replace the slideToggle -> Display:block; with a Display:none..

```
<div class="views-row">
    <div class="views-field-nothing">
        <span class="field-content">
            <span class="comments">COMMENTI</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="views-field-name">
        <span class="field-content">
            <span class="comments-toggle">Anonimo</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="views-row">
    <div class="views-field-nothing">
        <span class="field-content">
            <span class="comments">COMMENTI</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="views-field-name">
        <span class="field-content">
            <span class="comments-toggle">Utente A</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

once you click the second "Commenti" that is is in the "view-field-nothing" div the function .slideToggle() must write a display:block; in the html, like down here

```
 <div class="views-row">
   <div class="views-field-nothing">
      <span class="field-content">
          <span class="comments">COMMENTI</span>
      </span>
 </div>
 <div class="views-field-name">
    <span class="field-content">
        <span class="comments-toggle">Anonimo</span>
    </span>
 </div>
</div> 

<div class="views-row">
 <div class="views-field-nothing">
     <span class="field-content">
         <span class="comments">COMMENTI</span>
     </span>
</div>
<div class="views-field-name">
    <span class="field-content">
        <span class="comments-toggle" display:block;>Utente A</span>
     </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

if i click the first "COMMENTI" it should find the "Anonimo" string in the span and write at the end of the span a display:none;

```
 <div class="views-row">
   <div class="views-field-nothing">
      <span class="field-content">
          <span class="comments">COMMENTI</span>
      </span>
 </div>
 <div class="views-field-name">
    <span class="field-content">
        <span class="comments-toggle" style="display:none;">Anonimo</span>
    </span>
 </div>
</div> 

<div class="views-row">
 <div class="views-field-nothing">
     <span class="field-content">
         <span class="comments">COMMENTI</span>
     </span>
</div>
<div class="views-field-name">
    <span class="field-content">
        <span class="comments-toggle" style="display:block;">Utente A</span>
     </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.comments-toggle:contains('Anonimo')').hide()` will do the same as setting `display=none`

Comment: No, isn't working, because the .slideToggle() add a "display:block;" style to .comments-toggle and the .hide() function don't write a display:none

Comment: Set up a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the problem. Both of the answers below are valid problems with your code, you probably just need to combine them.

Comment: In the second scenario, do you want the `Anonimo` to hide/show (but not "slide") when clicking on its `COMMENTI`?

Comment: Anonimo is something that i don't want to be shown ever, is something that drupal put me there when there's no comment.. So if i click on "Commenti" and the script find "Anonimo" it doesn't have to show the whole span "comments-toggle"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/valerioMassacci/3mbMA/3/

Comment: I've updated my answer below. I think it should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Here's an updated script based on your updated question. It is possible to hide all the `Anonimo` spans initially and then check for using the slide animations on those that don't contain the `Anonimo`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comments-toggle:contains('Anonimo')").hide();
    $('.views-field-nothing').click(function(){
        var field = $(this).siblings('.views-field-name').find('.comments-toggle');
        if (field.text() != 'Anonimo')
            field.slideToggle("fast");
    });   
});
```

Here's the modified jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3mbMA/6/

Comment: It might help if you posted some of the related html.

Comment: <div class="views-row">      
  <div class="views-field-nothing">
   <span class="field-content">
      <span class="comments">COMMENTI</span>
   </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="views-field-name">
        <span class="field-content">  
          <span class="comments-toggle">Anonimo</span>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Yes, but in that way it take off Anonimo by clicking on "Commenti", i want that "Anonimo" string is not displayed in automatic if contained in the span.

Comment: Could you update the html in your question where you have both comments you want hidden and ones you to "slide"?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use double quotes `"` or escape single quote `\'`, if you are already in open brackets

```
$(".comments-toggle:contains('Anonimo')").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: tried, but the display:block; of .slideToggle() isn't replaced by a display:none;